Asking for clarification on how to interpret the output of a Generalized Additive Model with interaction terms
I'm very noob to GAM modeling, so I needed to clarify some questions, so thank you in advance :)
I want to model bacterial growth (numeric) as a function of the concentration (numeric) of two drugs (with levels D1 or D2), considering that by bacterial strain has two genotypes (with levels day G1 or G2). I'm using the mgcv R package. Since both the drug type and the genotype could affect growth differently and both treatments were applied to both genotypes I considered including the interaction between both variables and fitting a smooth per level. So I used the formula:
growth_data$Genotype_Drug <- interaction(growth_data$Genotype, growth_data$Drug)
growth_data$Genotype <- relevel(growth_data$Genotype, ref = "G1")
growth_data$Drug <- relevel(growth_data$Drug, ref = "D1")

gam_model <- gam(Growth ~ s(Concentration, k=5, by=Genotype_Drug) + Genotype * Drug, data = growth_data, method = "REML")

summary(gam_model)

Family: gaussian 
Link function: identity 

Formula:
Growth ~ s(Concentration, k=5, by=Genotype_Drug) + Genotype * Drug

Parametric coefficients:
                         Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)               353.491      2.056 171.928  < 2e-16 ***
GenotypeG2                  9.283      2.908   3.193  0.00465 ** 
DrugD2                     17.243      2.908   5.930 9.12e-06 ***
GenotypeG2:DrugD2           7.461      4.112   1.814  0.08495 .  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Approximate significance of smooth terms:
                                                  edf Ref.df     F  p-value    
s(Concentration):Genotype_DrugG2.D2             3.483  3.807 56.72  < 2e-16 ***
s(Concentration):Genotype_DrugG1.D2             3.089  3.481 32.72  < 2e-16 ***
s(Concentration):Genotype_DrugG2.D1             2.866  3.271 15.83 1.22e-05 ***
s(Concentration):Genotype_DrugG1.D1             2.937  3.339 11.45 0.000121 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

R-sq.(adj) =  0.941   Deviance explained = 96.7%
-REML = 111.67  Scale est. = 38.045    n = 36

So my questions:

Does that formula make sense for what I want to model?
In the parametric coefficients, does the significance for the comparison, say GenotypeG2, mean that when the drug is D1 (the reference level), genotype G2 grows better than genotype G1?
In the interaction GenotypeG2:DrugD2, does it mean that when genotype G2 is treated with D2, it does not grow significantly different than genotype G1 treated with D1?
If the intercept is the value of growth when genotype and drug are at the ference levels (G1 and D1), what does it mean that the smooth term s(Concentration):Genotype_DrugG1.D1 is significant?

Sorry if the questions are very basic, I'm trying to get this right :)

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Q1
The model formula you used fits the effects of interest. You might consider this alternative
Growth ~ s(Concentration, k = 5, bs = "sz") +
  s(Concentration, Genotype, k = 5, bs = "sz") +
  s(Concentration, Drug, k = 5, bs = "sz") +
  s(Concentration, Genotype, Drug, k = 5, bs = "sz")

which models the average effect of Concentration on Growth, and then smooth deviations from that average effect for the different groups formed by the factors. One of the advantages of this formulation is that you have a term in the summary() for each factor-smooth interaction, so you can test if you need the full set of smooths implied by the 3-way interaction of the last term. A disadvantage is that, all else equal, this model will use more basis functions and hence be more complex than the factor-by model you used.
What I'm not convinced by is the use of a Gaussian family for Growth; I doubt this will have constant variance: big things grow more. How did you derive Growth? If it was by differencing timepoints, then I think you'd be better off modelling the actual data (abundance or whatever), and then ask questions about changes in growth using the derivatives of the estimate growth curve.
Q2
Yes, on average.
Q3
No; the estimated effect is positive. To compute the estimated group means, sum up the coefficients for the levels indexing each group. For G1D1, we have simply the intercept: 353.491. The other terms are deviations from this number. So for

G1D1 we need 353.491
G1D2 we need 353.491 + 17.243,
G2D2 we need 353.491 + 17.243 + 7.461

hence G2D2 has a higher average value for Growth than G1D1.
Q4
The test for the smooths are against a $\text{H}_0: f_j(x) = 0 \, \forall \, x$  (i.e. that the value of the function $f$ for the $j$th group equals 0 for all values of $x$, or in other words, the null hypothesis is a flat, constant function with value 0.) What it means that the $f(\mathtt{Concentration)$ for the G1D1 group is significant is that there is evidence against the null hypothesis of a flat function, which would imply that as x varies, the effect of Concentration on the response varies about the estimated group mean (from the parametric effects).
